# AJAX url and controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

For form submission I use an AJAX call that posts data to a page like form.ajax.php. At this page I check if '_POST' is set and then process the form by validation, and then save the data using my database class. Depending on the result, the ajax-page return a status message back to the form-page which fires an alert message with the status.

My question is how and where should I put my AJAX files. Should I use one file for all kinds of AJAX requests or multiple and how does AJAX fit into web MVC? I have tried to search for it but there seems to be many different opinions.

Comment: You can choose whatever you want for structuring your app.
Ajax call doesn't brake your mvc pattern as it just makes an asynchronous request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually find it manageable to make ajax calls from the views files which load ajax(js) functions as needed. This way all the functionality related to the front end display is contained in one place and easier to debug later on. I also create common utility ajax functions so minimize code repetition.It goes something like this:

```
view.php( callController(ajax function) )  --ajax call-->  controller.php( return value)---> view.php(updateView(ajax function))
```

Comment: Thanks. So in a simple form submission how would your AJAX and controller interact. I guess they are two separate files?

Comment: First you load all the required JS(Ajax) files in the view and make a call to controller with the input data & when you get the return value you update the view. In case of non-ajax submit entire page(view) is refreshed.

Comment: So in other words. The controller in this case is the existing page the AJAX post to which return the JSON?

Comment: yeah kind of , I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks and to put all AJAX controllers separated in different files like @AnPel suggested?

Comment: its up to you , It is usually better if you have a large number of files.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for clarity, use one file per AJAX action, and put them all in the same directory, like `/AJAX/logout.ajax.php`, `/AJAX/login.ajax.php` etc. If you only have a couple of actions you can just use one file to serve them all.

This is just a matter of convention between you and the people you work with (including your future self, say 6 months later, when you will have no idea what you did in that project).

As long as everyone is in the same page, you can't really go wrong.

Also, I hope you sanitize your _POST inputs properly so little [Robert](https://xkcd.com/327/) won't be able to harm your database.